# Ajax Return Date from C# to ajax result

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, linq

Hi I have code that has a column Date in Linq.

when I call this code behind function using ajax it return the date column as "/Date(1464710400000)/"

How can I handle this??

This is my code:

```js
function SetSubsVal() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AccountManagement.aspx/GetModeofPayment",
            data: '{ptype: true, regid:' + $("#hdnRegID").val() + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.d.length != 0) {
                    $(result.d).each(function (i, data) {
                        try { $('#subsType').val(data.SubscriptionType.toString()); } catch (err) { }
                        try { $('#subscriptionfee').val(data.Fee.toString()); } catch (err) { }
                        try { $('#invRcptSub').val(data.InvoiceRecipient.toString()); } catch (err) { }
                        try {
                            debugger;
                            $('#invDateSub').val(data.InvoiceDate);
                        } catch (err) { }
                        try { $('#startDateSub').val(data.StartDate.toString()); } catch (err) { }
                        try { $('#endDateSub').val(data.EndDate.toString()); } catch (err) { }
                        try { $('#numberoforder').val(data.NumberOfOrder.toString()); } catch (err) { }
                        try { $('#ordersleft').val(data.OrderLeft.toString()); } catch (err) { }
                        try {
                            if (data.Active) {
                                prevSettup[0].SubsActive = '1';
                                $('#lblActive').trigger('click');

                            }
                        } catch (err) { }
                    })
                }
            }
            ,
            error: function (err) {

                alert(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here my code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<AccountPaymentMode> GetModeofPayment(bool ptype, int regid)
    {
        List<AccountPaymentMode> payments = new List<AccountPaymentMode>();

        using (EDMEntities entity = new EDMEntities())
        {

            payments = entity.AccountPaymentModes.Where(w => w.RegID == regid && w.IsSubscription == ptype).ToList();
        }


        return payments;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem/error you have ? Because, you can use it as a javacsript Date object.

Comment: try this $('#startDateSub').val(new Date(data.StartDate).toDateString());

Comment: It return like this "/Date(1464969600000)/"

Comment: ry this $('#startDateSub').val(new Date(data.StartDate).toDateString()); --Invalid Date